# Extract between patterns from first to Nth match and quit (gz, zcat | sed, awk, perl)

Tags: awk, sed, gzip, extract, large-files

Thanks for viewing this post. I will try to be clear and comprehensive in return!

Below the situation:

- Hundreds of ~GB size .gz archives
- List of wanted data that consists in identifiers. Each identifier is associated with the name of the unique archive in which to find the data.

Data structure of a .gz archive:

```
zcat archive.gz

    ...
    identifier_nth
    ...
    END_BLOCK
    ...
    ...
    ...
    identifier_1
    ...
    END_BLOCK
    ...
    ...
    ...
    identifier_1
    ...
    ...
    END_BLOCK
    ...
    ...
    identifier_nth
    ...
    END_BLOCK
    ...
    ...
    ...
    identifier_1
    ...
    END_BLOCK
    ...
    identifier_nth
    ...
    END_BLOCK
```

I currently do:

```
start=$(echo "$wanted_identifier_of_list") # I cat | while read through a list of thousands identifiers for the process (here $wanted_identifier_of_list = identifier_1)
end=$(echo "END_BLOCK")

zcat nth_archive.gz | sed -n "/${start}/,/${end}/p" > ${start}.dat
```

It works fine, but it is slow and there are too many blocks extracted for each identifier. I just need a fraction of them from first to Nth occurrence.

So I would like to:

1) limit the number of block I retrieve to an arbitrary number (here N = 2 for example)
2) quit both zcat/sed or whatever used after I completed or when I finish to read the archive.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Many thanks,

Florian

Comment: You said you will try to be clear and comprehensive. I'm afraid you failed. You showed us your inputs, and then jumped directly to your current code (which, presumably, doesn't do quite what you need it to do). You forgot to describe the task. What do you need to do (what is the exact logic, in detail) and what is the desired output. Please clarify.

Comment: and replace every `...` in your example with strings of characters such as would appear in your real data.

Answer (score 0):

something like this should work with early exit.  However, untested.

```
$ zcat ... | awk -v start="identifier_1" -v end="END_BLOCK" -v n=2 '
                     !f && $0~start{f=n} f; f && $0~end{f--; if(!f) exit}'
```

Comment: Hi karakfa. It works well for the exit and already save much time. However it looks like the counter is not functioning well. I think it is because for contiguous block with same ID the start tag block n+1 is on the same line and overlap with the end tag of block n.

Like:

nameString_identifier1

Comment: Perhaps a representative input sample will help someone to fix what's wrong with the script.

Answer (score -1):

Some more input below:
I use "##########                 Name:     ZINC000005215379" as start and "##########                 Name:" as stop currently.

```
...
##########                 Name:     ZINC000005215379
...

@<TRIPOS>MOLECULE
 ZINC000005215379      none
   58    62     1     0     0
...
@<TRIPOS>ATOM
      1 C1         -1.3168    -6.3293    -6.1200 C.3        1  LIG1  -0.1600
      2 C2         -0.1404    -5.3624    -5.9715 C.3        1  LIG1   0.0700
...
@<TRIPOS>BOND
     1    1    2 1
     2    1   41 1
...
##########                 Name:     ZINC000005215379
...

@<TRIPOS>MOLECULE
 ZINC000005215379      none
   58    62     1     0     0
...
@<TRIPOS>ATOM
      1 C1         -1.3168    -6.3293    -6.1200 C.3        1  LIG1  -0.1600
      2 C2         -0.1404    -5.3624    -5.9715 C.3        1  LIG1   0.0700
...
@<TRIPOS>BOND
     1    1    2 1
     2    1   41 1
...
##########                 Name:     ZINC000004473749
...

@<TRIPOS>MOLECULE
 ZINC000004473749      none
...
@<TRIPOS>ATOM

...
@<TRIPOS>BOND
     1    1    2 1
     2    1   41 1
...
```

Comment: Instead of posting this as an answer, it should have been [added to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61980577/edit). To prevent counting the *start* as an *end*, you could try adding a `next` statement to the answer which was given: `$0~start{f=n; next}`